# Stream to Apple TV

Tags: ubuntu

So, I have a presentation coming up. I decided the easiest way to present was to use the facility’s Apple TV. Unfortunately, no one seems to have found a way to activate the mirroring function on a Pi. Is this simply impossible, or is there something I’m missing?

Comment: Would be safer to plug your Pi into a TV or projector using hdmi.

Comment: @CoderMike The projector is out of reach, so I can’t easily connect a cable.